# Where should I place a Python package's demo script?

Tags: python, package, program-entry-point, demo, convention

I am coding a new python package to be used by others. To demonstrate how it should be used, I am writing a demo script that executes the main parts of the new package.

What is the convention for doing this, so that other will find the script easily? Should it be  a separate module (by what name)? Should it be located in the package's root directory? Out of the package? In `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen any real convention for this, but I personally put it in a main sentinel within `__init__.py` so that it can be invoked via `python -m somepackage`.

Comment: +1: I'd probably execute it only if a certain switch is present, such as `python -m somemodule --demo`. This would be consistent when adding other execution-modes, like running all tests.

Answer (score 3):

> Should it be a separate module (by what name)?

demo/some_useful_name.py

A demo directory contains demo scripts.  Similarly, a test directory contains all your unit tests.

> Should it be located in the package's root directory?

No.  It's not part of the package.  It's a demo.

> Out of the package?

Yes.

> In **init**.py?

Never.

---

A package has two lives.  (1) as uninstalled source, (2) in the lib/site-packages as installed code.

The "source" should include README, setup.py, demo directory, test directory, and the package itself.

The top-level "source" setup.py should install just the package.  The demo and test don't get installed.  They get left behind as part of the download.